# If control sequence under Gnuplot

Tags: if-statement, gnuplot

How to perform control sequences under Gnuplot please?
I need to make something like

```
if (x == nan)
  set xrange[]

else
  set xrange[10:30]
```

I tried something like

```
( x > 100000 ) ?  (set xrange[]) : (set xrange[10:30])
```

... buth without success! I spent hours trying to solve this!!
Any help please?
At worst I can create a shell script an manage this, but I think there should be some control sequences to fix this.

Comment: Where does `x` come from? gnuplot has an `if (...) { } else {}` construct.

Comment: Hi Christoph! In fact I have my own script that input 'x' as a parameter to gnuplot file.

Comment: So what about `if (x > 10000) { set xrange[*:*] } else { set xrange[10:30]}`?

Comment: As you suggest, I tried this 'if(2==3){  set xrange[] } else {set xrange[10:30]}', but it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean with 'doesn't work'? For me it works fine, but requires version 4.6. But `set xrange []` does nothing, to use autoscaling use e.g.`set xrange[*:*]` or `set autoscale x`.

Comment: The issue is not with 'set range[]'. I already tried it. The issue is with the manner Am using 'if'. P.S Am using Gnuplot 4.4

Comment: `xrange[*:*]` does not work for me. By "Does not work" I mean I have an error message. The code breaks.

Comment: With 4.4.4 the following works for me: `x = 2; if (x == 3) set autoscale x; else set xrange [10:30];`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For gnuplot 4.4.4 the `if` statement must be on a single line:

```
if (x > 10000) set autoscale x; else set xrange [10:30]
```

or use `\` to continue on the next line.

```
if (x > 10000) \
    set autoscale x; \
else \
    set xrange [10:30]
```

Since 4.6.0 gnuplot can use brackets to delimit the branches:

```
if (x > 10000) {
    set autoscale x
} else {
    set xrange [10:30]
}
```