# How to map a string to a RGB value?

Tags: gnuplot

The data file is like the following:

```
# ID,Value, Region
A,30,North
B,26,North
C,49,South
D,55,East
...
```

Here I would like to map the string (e.g., `Region`) to a rgb value which will be used as the `lc` color for `boxxy`. It can be described as the pseudo-code:

```
if (region eq "North") {
   "0x1b9e77"
} else if (region eq "South") {
   "0xd95f02"
} else if (region eq "East") {
   "0x7570b3"
} else  {
   "0xe7298a"
}
```

How can I achieve such mapping in gnuplot? Here, in fact, it is to map `$3` to a hex string in `using` option.

Comment: On *nix system, this usually involves sed/awk... I guess mingw32 helps on windows?

Comment: @wwweagle can it be done in gnuplot only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a mapping function basing on your pseudocode:

```
colormapper(x)=(x eq "North"?0x1b9e77:(x eq "South"?0xd95f02:(x eq"East"?0x7570b3:0xe7298a)))
```

after that, you can apply it on your column.

```
plot 'map.dat' u 1:2:(colormapper(stringcolumn(3))) pt 7 ps 3 lc rgb variable notitle
```

[image: Sample based on my data]

The key moments of the solution:

- Using `x eq "North"...` because we compare strings
- `lc rgb variable` let us to control the line color by a variable (without `rgb` you can access to the standard line colors)
- Using `stringcolumn(3)` instead of `$3` is very important.

Comment: Cool! The key point is `stringcolumn`. BTW, can we simplify the nested ternary operator?

Comment: I fear that we can't. There is `if` statement in gnuplot (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20360672/6113363), but this is for control sequences as there is no such thing as `return`.

Comment: @chenzhongpu it depends what you consider simplified. If you have more than a few items, a lookup table might be clearer and easier to maintain. Check this recent answer about lookups: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289393/7295599

Comment: @theozh The lookup table is a good idea.